# How to manage nested API's in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nested, fetch-api, openweathermap

I am using **openweather API**. This is my code so far.:

**index.html**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="field">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Enter"
      style="width: 400px"
    />
    <button class="go">Go</button>
    <button class="second">Get 7 days data</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
let input = document.querySelector("input");
let btn = document.querySelector(".go");
let show = document.querySelector(".second");

btn.addEventListener("click", load);

function load() {

  const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${input.value}/apikey`;
  console.log(url);

  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      let lo = data.coord.lon;
      let la = data.coord.lat;

      const link = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${la}&lon=${lo}/apikey`;
      console.log(link);

      return fetch(link);
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((dat) => {
      console.log(dat);
    });
}
```

As you can see the second API needs the latitude and longitude value from the first API.
I want weather information displayed when I click on **Go** button and information of seven days forecast when I click on **Get 7 days data** button. This console logs the URL and the API works just fine, but I want to have separate info displayed when clicking different buttons.

I know both urls get console logged because that's where my main function runs on click. How do I add event listener on click and have two separate functions when the two APIs depend on each other?

Comment: Try storing the results from the first API call in global variables and then you can use them on the second API call

Answer (score 0):

We can assign another `click` event handler to the 7DaysForecast button. When the user clicks on the first button to fetch the current weather, just the first API call will be hit and result will be displayed.

When user hits the second button, first API call will be hit, the latitude and longitude info will be fetched and then the forecast API call will be hit and the result will be shown to the user on completion of the call.

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");
let btn = document.querySelector(".go");
let show = document.querySelector(".second");

btn.addEventListener("click", load);
show.addEventListener("click", get7DaysWeatherForecast);

function getWeatherData() {
  fetch(getWeatherAPIUrl(input.value)).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  });
}

function getWeatherAPIUrl(value) {
  return `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${value}/apikey`;
}

function load() {
  getWeatherData().then((res) => console.log(res));
}

function get7DaysWeatherForecast() {
  getWeatherData()
    .then((data) => {
      let lo = data.coord.lon;
      let la = data.coord.lat;

      const link = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${la}&lon=${lo}/apikey`;

      return fetch(link);
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((dat) => {
      console.log(dat);
    });
}
```